# Rails - Upload picture to Facebook using URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, amazon-s3

I'm using `Koala` for Facebook API and `Paperclip` for Amazon S3.

I already finished the code for S3 Upload, but having problem for Facebook's upload.

Here's my simplified code:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:access_token])
file = open(@user.photo.url(:origin)).read

# ALBUM_ID is constant, its value is the Facebook's album ID
@graph.put_picture(file, { }, ALBUM_ID)
```

I keep getting this error on last line:

```
ArgumentError

string contains null byte
```

I think the way I set `file` is wrong but I can't find other way to do it.

Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While uploading picture on facebook using URL, you just need to send picture url directly (you **don't** need to send binary data).

```
# REMOVE THIS LINE
file = open(@user.photo.url(:origin)).read
```

Update API call as:

```
# ALBUM_ID is constant, its value is the Facebook's album ID
@graph.put_picture(@user.photo.url(:origin), {}, ALBUM_ID)
```

Some other ways to use `put_picture` method:

```
  #     put_picture(file, content_type, {:message => "Message"}, 01234560)
  #     put_picture(params[:file], {:message => "Message"})
  #     # with URLs, there's no optional content type field
  #     put_picture(picture_url, {:message => "Message"}, my_page_id)
```

Source: [**Koala**](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/master/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb#L201) gem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I keep getting `Unknown error 500` from Facebook which most probably caused by the URL from Paperclip has extension like `.../my-image.jpg?140583423`. I tried **hard-coding** the URL without that extension and works. Any way to disable that extension?

Comment: If I understood your comment, `@user.photo.url(:origin).split('?')[0]` can work for you